# Convert image to pdf fail by unknow file extension

Tags: python, image, pdf

I have the following code that loops through all the images with any extension in multiple folders then to convert those images to pdf
I am stuck at the last line of saving the pdf file

```
from PIL import Image
import os

path = 'MAIN'
ext = ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.bmp', '.tif', '.tiff']

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if(file.endswith(tuple(ext))):
            sFilePath = os.path.join(root,file)
            print(sFilePath.split('.')[0])
            img = Image.open(sFilePath)
            img = img.convert('RGB')
            img.save(os.path.join(sFilePath.split('.')[0], '.pdf'))
```

Another point I need to add is to delete the image file after converting it to pdf

@martineau as for your awesome solution you provided, I tried to change the way I convert the image to pdf using img2pdf
Here's my try

```
import img2pdf
with open(path_object.parent / (path_object.stem + '.pdf'), 'wb') as f:
    f.write(img2pdf.convert(str(path_object)))
```

with the images with the alpha channel, I got this message
`Image contains an alpha channel which will be stored as a separate soft mask (/SMask) image in PDF.`

This is snaphot of the error message related to the alpha-channel images
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another yet way to do things that makes use the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#) module which allows file and folder paths to be tried as objects and manipulated via an [object-oriented programming paradigm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) or model — which often results in very concise code:

```
from pathlib import Path
from PIL import Image

path = Path('./images')
exts = {'.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.bmp', '.tif', '.tiff'}

for path_object in path.glob('**/*'):
    if path_object.is_file() and path_object.suffix in exts:
        img = Image.open(path_object)
        img = img.convert('RGB')
        img.save(path_object.parent / (path_object.stem+'.pdf'))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried both codes and they are very well but sometimes I got errors with alpha channel images. How can I fix such a problem?

Comment: As for this code the pdf name has the extension of the image. How can I get the stem name only?. I could solve it by replacing `path_object.name` with `path_object.stem`

Comment: `path_object.stem` seems to work properly — see updated answer. Converting the images to `RGB` should get rid of any Alpha channel they might of had, but without seeing the exact error message you are getting I can't provide any help on that unrelated issue.

Comment: I have updated the question to show you the problem of using another package which is img2pdf.

Comment: Never mind. I could solve it by converting the object to string `f.write(img2pdf.convert(str(path_object)))`

Comment: While some if not all of the Python standard library has been modified to accept either strings or `pathlib` path objects as arguments, many third-party modules still do not. You should report the problem to the `img2pdf` author (adding support is trivial).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Have you seen the snapshot of the alpha channel problem?

Comment: Yes. From what's in the screenshot it doesn't look like the .tif image was converted to RGB before feeding it to `img2pdf.convert()` (which would have gotten rid of any Alpha channel data in it).

Comment: How can I fix that? I have tried for several hours but with no success.

Comment: I don't know. The issue is with `img2pdf` and is not directly related to this question anyway (or at least the code you have in it — regardless of its title). That said, it [looks to me](https://pypi.org/project/img2pdf/) like `img2pdf` only supports monochrome tiff files.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using the [`os.path.splitext()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) function to get base part of the image's filename, and then combine that plus the `.pdf` extension you want using `os.path.join()`. (Note that converting it to `RGB` is **not** the same as converting it to PDF format.)

```
from PIL import Image
import os

path = './'
ext = ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.bmp', '.tif', '.tiff']

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(tuple(ext)):
            src_image_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            base_name = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
            img = Image.open(src_image_path)
            img = img.convert('RGB')
            img.save(os.path.join(root, base_name+'.pdf'))
```